# How to access the properties of a viewController, iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uitableview, appdelegate

I have two view controllers UIViewController and a UITableViewController in a storyboard. I want to access the properties of the UITableViewController from the UIViewController. How do I do this? Do I need to use the AppDelegate (how?), or is there another method?

**EDIT** I'm currently adding the following code to the appDelegate, which has a property: tableViewController.

```
MyTableViewController *tvc = [[MyTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyTableViewController" bundle:nil];
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.tableViewController = tvc;
```

I am attempting to assign a property of the tableViewController in another viewController like below, but the property is NULL.

```
MyTableViewController *tvc = (MyTableViewController*)appDelegate.tableViewController;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to access the properties of another class first you need to import .h file where you want and make object of that class and then access the property you want.

Suppose you need to access the second view controller properties in 
FirstViewController.Then define SecondViewController.h file in FirstViewController.m and make object

```
SecondViewController *controller = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:Nil];

controller.property;
```

Comment: I want to access a property.

Answer (score 1):

Expose the desired sub-view controllers as properties of the view controller that contains them.

Expose your root view controller(s) as properties of your app delegate, and synthesize them also.

When you want to access a different UIViewController, first obtain a reference to your appDelegate:

```
MyAppDelegate* myAppDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Then just use your chain of properties to get access to your desired view controller.

```
SubSubViewController* ssvc = myAppDelegate.rootViewController.subViewController.subSubViewController;
```